# Wrong Number of Characters (String Munipulation from File) -- Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, java-io

I am currently testing out a program who's purpose is to import a file and find the number of characters in that file using string manipulation.

I am currently using `System.out.println(fileone.length());` to do so. However each time I try and run the program it reads the number of characters wrong, in fact it gives the same wrong number every time. Down below is the output of the program.

My name is Sam Tyler    54

As you can see the words in the file are displayed and next to that is the character number which is obviously wrong, as I counted myself, it should be 19, including spaces.

Here is the code that is reading the file and giving the character number.

Can you see any problems?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Scanner ourScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileone));
System.out.println();

while(ourScanner.hasNextLine()) 
{
    System.out.print (ourScanner.nextLine() + "\t");
    count++;
    if (count%4 == 0)
        System.out.println();               
    }
}           
//System.out.println ("\n\n" + count + " \ntotal strings found.");
System.out.println(fileone.length());
```

Comment: Is fileone the String name of your file?  If so, you are printing out the number of characters in the name of your file.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the length of the `String` representing the file path (`fileone`), not the actual file scanned, so it will be invariant given the context.

If you're counting the number of lines, just print your `count` variable.

You also have a number of ways to check for file `length` from a `File` object , or for specific character length (since the file system may allocate more space than actually used for the file), you can count them through iteration with a `FileReader`, etc.

Comment: Cheers for the help, got me exploring FileReader a bit more, makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

`fileone.length()` gives you the length of the path of file.
But `new File(fileone).length()` will give you the file size in number of bytes (assuming one character is one byte)

Comment: Thanks, FileReader makes sense, and can work, but this line helps me from changing up my code too much!

Comment: just to confirm...I'm trying to stop the program from counting the spaces...at the moment I am using System.out.println(new File(fileName).replace(" ", "").length()); ---- it appears to having problem with the replace. Any ideas? It is telling me that the "method replace (String,String) is undefined for type File.

Comment: replace is for strings. Not for file object. You have to read the content of file as string and then apply replace on it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this example:**

**1:** read all the lines of the file

**2:** convert to a string

**3:** remove the white spaces

**4:** display the length in byte for the resulting string

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\test.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuffer fileContents = new StringBuffer();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            fileContents.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        String sValue = fileContents.toString();

        //remove all whitespace
        sValue = sValue.replaceAll("\\s+","");

        System.out.println(sValue.length());
    }
}
```

**Test:**

test.txt content:  `My name is Sam Tyler 54`  --> 18 characters

result:
18